# How to resolve IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant ClientRequest.TwoNumbersEnum.1 in Java?

Tags: java, enums, illegalargumentexception

I'm learning Java and Enum and I have this enum:

```
public static enum TwoNumbersEnum {
    _1("1"),
    _0("0");
```

After that I try to set value "1" for an object:

```
theClient.setTwoNumbers(ClientRequest
        .TwoNumbersEnum.valueOf("1"));
```

And when I try to set this I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.dgs.ClientRequest.TwoNumbersEnum.1
```

How can I resolve the problem? I think this problem is only for numbers. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `valueOf` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Enum.valueOf` is used to return the enum constant from a string. You have used `TwoNumbersEnum.valueOf("1")` and there is no enum with constant name `"1"` (Not possible as its a number.)

You have to call it like `TwoNumbersEnum.valueOf("_1")`.

You can write a access method in the enum definition to access the value of it directly. Like below

```
public static enum TwoNumbersEnum {
        
        _1("1"),
        _0("0");
        private final String value;
        private TwoNumbersEnum(String val) {
            this.value = val;
        }
        public String value() {
            return this.value;
        }
        
    }
```

and then call it like `TwoNumbersEnum.valueOf("_1").value()` if you need the value itself. refer to documentation for more.